# Are users supposed to delete a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Are users supposed to delete a closed question?

Is there any harm in leaving it in closed state?

If the asker does not delete it, can others continue to down vote it?

Comment: Self deleted posts contribute to [tag:post-bans], so be careful while deleting.

Answer (score 1):

> Are users supposed to delete a closed question?

If the question is gawd-awful and has no hope for redemption, then yes, delete it, but otherwise if it seems even slightly potentially salvageable, then you should not vote to delete it immediately, but rather leave a comment on how it should be improved, or edit it to improve it if possible, and thereby give the original poster a chance at making it answerable.

> Is there any harm in leaving it in closed state?

No, I don't think so. If it is closed, has been down-voted, and there are no up-voted answers, I believe that it will be automatically deleted in a few days.

> If the asker does not delete it, can others continue to down vote it?

As long as it has not been deleted, it can be up or down voted. But it can **also** be edited and improved, and thus hopefully rendered answerable.